# Create Custom report in admin using Magento 2.1.9

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, reports, custom-reports

I want to create a custom report using the custom table section in the admin under the reports menu. COuld you please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

I have found one extension created for custom report. It contains sample code with needed file and uploaded on github.

You can look at below URL. https://github.com/yash7690/magento2-customreport

Answer (score 3):

free extension 
https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-advanced-reports.html

OR

I used this module https://github.com/degdigital/magento2-customreports/
and customize to my needs.